# A family of commuting endomorphisms is semisimple if each element is semisimple

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If $\phi : V \rightarrow V$ is an endomorphism of a finite-dimensional (say real) vector space, $\phi$ is called "semisimple" if any $\phi$-invariant subspace of $V$ has a complimentary $\phi$-invariant subspace ($W \subset V$ is $\phi$-invariant if $\phi (W) \subset W$). We say that a collection $\Phi= \{ \phi_i\}_{i \in I}$ of such endomorphisms is semisimple if any subspace which is invariant under every element of $\Phi$ has a complimentary subspace which is invariant under every element of $\Phi$.

How can I prove that

"**If $\Phi$ is a *commuting* family of endomorphisms then $\Phi$ is semisimple if each $\phi_i$ is semisimple**"?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3948266/96384

Answer (score 6):

Short answer : this is because “semisimple” equals “diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$”.

The details :

Working on $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb R$, our initial space
$V$ become another vector space which we denote by $T(V)$, 
(others denote it by $V \otimes {\mathbb C}$) and we have
a $\mathbb R$-linear bijection $T : V\to T(V)$. Similarly, any 
$\phi : V \to V$ induces a map $T(\phi) : T(V) \to T(V)$
defined in the obvious way (if $B$ is a $\mathbb R$-basis of $V$,
then the matrix of $T(\phi)$ relatively to $T(B)$ is the same as
the matrix of $\phi$ relatively to $B$). Also, let us
put $T\Phi=\lbrace T\phi | \phi \in \Phi \rbrace$, for any
$\Phi \subseteq {\sf End}(V)$.

**Lemma 1 (Engel’s Lemma)** Let $\Phi$ be a commuting family in
${\sf End}(V)$. Then there is a nonzero vector $v\in T(V)$ which
is an eigenvector of every $\phi\in T(\Phi)$.

**Proof of lemma 1** We argue by induction on $d={\sf dim}(V)$. If
$d\leq 1$ the result is obvious. So assume that $d\geq 2$ and that the
result holds for any $d'<d$. Let $\Phi$ be a commuting family in
${\sf End}(V)$. If $\Phi$ consists only of homotheties (i.e. multiples
of the identity), then any $v$ will do the job. Otherwise there is
a $\phi\in V$ which is not a homothety. By the fundamental theorem of
algebra, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{\phi}$of $\phi$ can be factorized
as $\chi_{\phi}(x)=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^r (x-\lambda_k)^{m_k}$ where
the $\lambda_k$ are distinct complex numbers and the $m_k$ are integers
summing to $n$. Since $\phi$ is not a homothety, we must have $r>1$. Consider 
the characteristic susbpace $W={\sf Ker}((T(\phi)-\lambda_1{\sf id})^{m_1})$. Since any 
$\psi \in T(\Phi)$ commutes with $\phi$ and hence with $(T(\phi)-\lambda_1{\sf id})^{m_1}$ also, we see that $W$ is invariant by every $\psi \in T(\Phi)$. Since
${\sf dim}(W)<{\sf dim}(V)$, by the induction hypothesis there is a
$w\in W$ which is an eigenvector of every $\phi\in T(\Phi)$, and this finishes 
the proof.

**Lemma 2(semisimple equals diagonalizable)** Let $\phi \in {\sf End}(V)$. Then
$\phi$ is semisimple iff $T(\phi)$ is diagonalizable, i.e. iff there is a basis
$B'$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $T(\phi)$ relatively to $B'$
is diagonal.

**Proof of lemma 2** Let $\phi \in {\sf End}(V)$, and  let $\chi_{\phi}$ be the 
characteristic polynomial of $\phi$. By the fundamental theorem of
algebra, the characteristic polynomial $\chi_{\phi}$of $\phi$ can be factorized
as $\chi_{\phi}(x)=\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^r (x-\lambda_k)^{m_k}$ where
the $\lambda_k$ are distinct complex numbers and the $m_k$ are integers
summing to $n$. Let $C_j={\sf Ker}((T(\phi)-\lambda_j{\sf id})^{m_j})$ be
the $j$-th characteristic space. Then $T(V)$ is the direct sum of the $C_j$, and in fact any $\phi$-invariant subspace $W$ of $T(V)$ will be the direct sum of the  $W\cap W_j$.

Suppose $\phi$ is semisimple. The eigenspace 
 $E_j={\sf Ker}((T(\phi)-\lambda_j{\sf id}))$ is a subspace of $C_j$, and is 
 invariant by $\phi$. By semisimplicity, there is a $\phi$-invariant $F_j$ with
 $T(V)=E_j\oplus F_j$. Now $F_j$ is the direct sum of the $F_j\cap C_k$ as noted 
 above, and hence $C_j=E_j \oplus (F_j \cap C_j)$. By definition of $E_j$, the 
 linear map $T(\phi)-\lambda_j{\sf id}$ is injective on $F_j \cap C_j$, but at 
 the same time $(T(\phi)-\lambda_j{\sf id})^{m_j}$ is zero on $F_j \cap C_j$. This 
 imples $F_j\cap C_j=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$, so $C_j=E_j$. Then $T(V)$ is the direct sum
 of the $E_j$ and $T(\phi)$ is diagonalizable.

Conversely, suppose $T(\phi)$ is diagonalizable. The eigenvalues of $T(\phi)$
 are either real (call those $\rho_1,\rho_2,\ldots ,\rho_s$), or they come
 in conjugate pairs (call those $\alpha_1\pm \beta_1i, \ldots, \alpha_s\pm \beta_si$). If we define in $V$ the characteristic spaces
 $C_k={\sf Ker}(\phi-\rho_k {\sf id})$ and $D_k={\sf Ker}((\phi-\alpha_k{\sf id})^2+
 (\beta_k)^2{\sf id})$,  any $\phi$-invariant subspace of $C_k$ or $D_k$
 has an invariant complement in $C_k$ or $D_k$. So $\phi$ is semisimple.

**Lemma 3(semisimple equals diagonalizable again)** Let $\Phi \subseteq {\sf End}(V)$. 
We say that   $T(\Phi)$ is diagonalizable when  there is a basis
$B'$ of $V$ such that the matrix of $T(\phi)$ relatively to $B'$
is diagonal, for every $\phi\in \Phi$.
If $T(\Phi)$ is diagonalizable then $\Phi$ is semisimple.
The converse holds for a commuting family : 
If $\Phi$ is commuting and semisimple, then  $T(\Phi)$ is diagonalizable.

**Proof of lemma 3**  If $T(\Phi)$ is 
diagonalizable, then we may (as in the final part of the proof
of lemma 2) decompose $T(V)$ as a sum of characteristic spaces,
in which every invariant subspace has an “internal” invariant complement.
So $\Phi$ is semisimple.

Conversely, suppose that $\Phi$ is semisimple and commuting. By Engel's lemma, there
is a vector $v_1$ which is an eigenvector for every $\phi\in V$. Since $\Phi$
is semisimple, there is a $\Phi$-invariant subspace $G$ with
$V={\sf span}(v_1)\oplus G$. By Engel's lemma, there
is a vector $v_2\in G$ which is an eigenvector for every $\phi\in V$. Iterating this
procedure (which must terminate since $V$ has finite dimension), we eventually
obtain a basis in which the matrix of every $\phi\in \Phi$ is diagonal as wished.

Now we can proceed to the proof of the properties you're asking.

**Theorem 1.** Let $\Phi$ be a commuting family in ${\sf End}(V)$. If every
$\phi \in \Phi$ is semisimple, then $\Phi$ is semisimple.

**Proof of theorem 1.** By Engel's lemma, there
is a vector $v_1$ which is an eigenvector for every $\phi\in V$. Since $\Phi$
is semisimple, there is a $\Phi$-invariant subspace $G$ with
$V={\sf span}(v_1)\oplus G$. By Engel's lemma, there
is a vector $v_2\in G$ which is an eigenvector for every $\phi\in V$. Iterating this
procedure (which must terminate since $V$ has finite dimension), we eventually
obtain a basis in which the matrix of every $\phi\in \Phi$ is diagonal.

So $T\Phi$ is diagonalizable, and we are now done by lemma 3.

**Theorem 2.** Let $\Phi$ be a commuting family in ${\sf End}(V)$. If 
$\Phi$ is semisimple, then every $\phi \in \Phi$ is semisimple.

**Proof of theorem 2.** If $\Phi$ is semisimple, then by lemma 3 $T\Phi$
is diagonalizable. So  $T\phi$ is diagonalizable for every $\phi\in\Phi$,
which means that every $\phi\in\Phi$ is semisimple by lemma 2.

Comment: Can you clarify your proof of Lemma 3? I cannot even see it clearly in the case where the field is $\mathbb R$ and its algebraic closure is $\mathbb C$. In my context, I need it where $\mathbb R$ is replaced by an arbitrary field of characteristic zero $F$, and it is not quite obvious to me how to proceed.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Which part do you want clarified ? The proof works for any field of characteristic zero, by the way ($\mathbb C$ has to be replaced by the algebraic closure of the field.)

Comment: The part $T(\Phi)$ diagonalizable implies $\Phi$ semisimple. I can find an eigenbasis for $T(V)$ which simultaneously diagonalizes all elements of $T(\Phi)$, and given $W \le V$ a $\Phi$-invariant subspace, $T(W)$ has a complement $W'$ in $T(V)$ which is invariant under $T(\Phi)$, but I don't see how that gives me $V = W \oplus W''$ for some $W''$ which is $\Phi$-invariant. That "internal" invariant complement business is not quite clear to me either. Thanks!

Comment: What? The $\mathbb R$-linear map $T : V \to \mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb R} V$ is not bijective! Real dimensions do not even agree...

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva You're right, $T$ is only injective. The real argument is the one I alluded to in my original solution, that if $W$ is invariant, $W$ must be "internal", i.e. must be a direct of $C_k$'s and $D_k$'s (in the notation of the proof of lemma 2). We then find a complement that is "internal" also

Comment: So I guess my question is how to do that. When $\Phi$ has one element it is obvious, but even for two elements it isn't!

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Notice that in the definition of a diagonalizable family ( in lemma 2), there is one single basis that diagonalizes all the $\phi\in \Phi$ at the same time. This is a much stronger condition that just asking every $\phi\in\Phi$ to be diagonalizable. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: No, because this basis is not unique, so I cannot assume that part of it is contained in my stable subspace. Otherwise I would just extend that basis and I would be done. Just think of the case where all the endomorphisms are multiples of the identity, the basis is definitely not unique

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54373/discussion-between-ewan-delanoy-and-patrick-da-silva).